# How to circle moving objects using opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, background-subtraction, connected-components

I have a video file and I need to circle all moving objects in a certain frame I select. My idea of a solution to this problem is:
 Circle all moving objects (white areas) on a video on which was applied motion detector and circle the same areas on the original frame.

I am using BackgroundSubtractorGMG() from cv2 to detect movement

Below I show the way I expect this program to work(I used to paint, so I am now sure this is correct, but I hope it is good enough to demonstrate the concept)

[image: The original frame]

[image: The frame with applied motion detector and selected moving objects]

[image: The final result]

Comment: And what is the result of your existing code?

Comment: I don't have any actual results, sorry

Comment: Do you actually want circles or just boxes drawn?

Comment: You can use this approach: take the binary result from the BackgroundSubtractorGMG, apply [Morphological Transformations](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#morphological-transformations) to remove noise, detect white shapes using [findContours](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_begin/py_contours_begin.html#contours-getting-started),

Comment: then draw the [boundingrect](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_features/py_contour_features.html#bounding-rectangle) for each contour.

Comment: Boxes. I did not know how to say it..."circle with boxes?"

Comment: I will try your approach, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said in comments:

1. Get the mask from you background subtraction algorithm
2. use cv.findContours(mask, ...) to find contours
3. (optional) select which contours you want to keep (something like                 `((x, y), radius) = cv.minEnclosingCircle(contour)` or `a, b, w, h = cv.boundingRect(c)`
    and `if radius > 5`
4. use [drawing functions](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/drawing_functions.html) like cv.rectangle or similar to draw the shape around the contour (like so: `cv.rectangle(img, (a, b), (a + w, b + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)`)